# Replace text in loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can't implement auto-replacement of text in the loop. The text is either not replaced, or is replaced randomly and not in the whole loop.
Help, please.

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "111", "password", "222");  
 $query1 ="SELECT * FROM beta ORDER BY ID DESC"; 
 $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query1);
?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("cost").html($("cost").html().replace('One', 'Two'));
});  
</script>
```

```
<cost>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="employee_data" class="row-border order-column cell-border hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>  
<th width="10%">1</th>
<th width="10%">2</th>
<th width="10%">3</th>
<th width="10%">4</th>
<th width="10%">5</th>
<th width="10%">6</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
echo '
<tr>
<td><font face="Verdana">'.$row1["name"].'</font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.$row1["len"].'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["len"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.$row1["myt"].'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["myt"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.$row1["tr"].'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["tr"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.$row1["kr"].'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["kr"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.$row1["var"].'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["var"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.$row1["kor"].'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["kor"].'" /></font></td>
</tr>
';  
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</cost>
```

The word "One" between <cost></cost> must be replaced by "Two".

Don't judge me too harshly, I'm new at this.

Big thnx!

Comment: I don't see any `<cost>` tags in the code you shared

Comment: @apokryfos at the beginning of the third block

Comment: Should this have the `Java` tag or `Javascript` tag?

Comment: @SedJ601 Yes, you're right. Corrected.

Comment: I missed that. JS .replace function only does 1 replacement if you use it without regex and the /g flag so here you could possibly get it to work `$("cost").html($("cost").html().replace(/One/g, 'Two'))` or use `replaceAll`

Comment: @apokryfos solved with preg_replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it from the  php side using str_replace function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
<?php
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
echo '
<tr>
<td><font face="Verdana">'.$row1["name"].'</font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.str_replace("One","Two",$row1["len"]).'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["len"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.str_replace("One","Two",$row1["myt"]).'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["myt"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.str_replace("One","Two",$row1["tr"]).'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["tr"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.str_replace("One","Two",$row1["kr"]).'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["kr"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.str_replace("One","Two",$row1["var"]).'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["var"].'" /></font></td>
<td><font color=#1341EB face="Verdana"><b>'.str_replace("One","Two",$row1["kor"]).'</b><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-offers" name="checkbox" value="'.$row1["kor"].'" /></font></td>
</tr>
';  
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Mina! Yes, it works.
There is another problem. Sometimes $row1["len"] returns an empty value. In html it looks like <b></b>. Can this empty value be replaced with arbitrary text? For example <b>text</b>.

Comment: I think In this case you need to check what has been stored in the database.